# Updating application from Google Play doesn't work, new installation works good

Tags: android, proguard

There is the following problem: there was some application on Google Play, it worked good. I added one feature and ProGuard protection and uploaded a new version on Google Play. Some users downloaded my application and it didn't work for it, but some of them deleted it and installed again - it worked! May it be problem with Proguard or not? I don't understand why it  happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use the same key to sign your app?

Comment: Yes I did. Only I added without little changes in code it was ProGuard

Comment: Did you change the sharedUserId in the manifest?

Comment: No. I changed versionName and versionCode only

Comment: Have you tried installing the old version and then upgrading - using adb - in order to replicate the problem?

Comment: No. I updated through Google Play only.